# Hibernate configuration with tomcat and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, tomcat6

I'm creating a webApp in eclipse using tomcat & hibernate (for mysql). Ive unit tested by code and I am able to connect to the db and pull data, but I'm running into issues when trying it from the web app.

From the exception it looks like it isnt able to get to the hibernate.cfg.xml, but I've tried placing the file in the src folder, WEB-INF/lib &  WEB-INF/classes but I still get the same error.

The line of code that it's failing on is:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
```

I would really really appreciate any help!

ClassPath References:
[image: ClassPath References]

Project References:
[image: Project References]

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:324)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:289)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:293)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:170)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:221)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:324)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:289)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:293)
```

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @Engineer, I was able to solve this by removing the jars from WEF-INF/lib & from the class path of the run configuration. Then I added them back using the "Deployment Assembly" menu in eclipse. I also have my project references here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Ranga Reddy](http://myjourneyonjava.blogspot.fr/2013/12/caused-by-javalangnullpointerexception.html):

> **Problem:**  Because of adding the jars in user library class path.
>
> **Solution:**  Instead of adding the jar files using User Library add the jars using classpath.

Comment: How about the reference to other projects? How should that be added? Also what libraries need to be in WEB-INF/lib?